# Auto scroll overflow text with CSS3

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a limited area to show a long text. It should be wrapped with ellipsis. When you mouse over it, it should be scrolled until end of it so I came up with [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tU43F/12/) but I have some problems.

1. It doesn't work on Opera Browser.
2. It uses static width property.

   ```
   div.content:hover {

      width:742px;

   }
   ```
3. Even text is shorter; it scrolls in a static duration.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: I solved all these problems with JavaScript but a pure CSS3 solution will be still great because I hate injecting CSS rules inside of my JavaScript Code. http://fiddle.jshell.net/tU43F/18/

Answer (score 1):

test with this : (u can modify the right attributes in animation same as u want)

```
div.content:hover {
    -webkit-animation: slide 5.0s linear;
    -moz-animation: slide 5.0s linear;
    -o-animation: slide 5.0s linear;
    animation: slide 5.0s linear;
    width:742px;
    right:0px;
    text-overflow: clip;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% { right:-665px;}
    50% { right:-340px;}
    100% { right:-0px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide {
    0% { right:-665px;}
    50% { right:-340px;}
    100% { right:-0px; }
}

@-o-keyframes slide {
    0% { right:-665px;}
    50% { right:-340px;}
    100% { right:-0px; }
}

@-khtml-keyframes slide {
    0% { right:-665px;}
    50% { right:-340px;}
    100% { right:-0px; }
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% { right:-665px;}
    50% { right:-340px;}
    100% { right:-0px; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I don't need a custom animation for linear transition. I just wanna give a dynamic duration depending on text width and it is achieved my last edit with js.